# ¿Como obtener el intervalo de pago de un producto de suscripcion simple en Woocommerce?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Tengo productos de suscripcion simple en mi sitio y estoy intentando obtener el intervalo de tiempo de pago de los productos. Para obtener los precios uso:

> wc_get_product

y el metodo:

> get_price()

Pero no he encontrado ningun metodo para obtener el intervalo de cobro de la suscripcion. Desde ya gracias por sus ayudas!

Answer (score 1):

Para hacer referencia a la información de la orden suscripción use la clase

```
WC_Subscriptions_Order
```

y para consultar el intervalo de la suscripción

```
$order = new WC_Order($order_id);
$interval = WC_Subscriptions_Order::get_subscription_interval( $order );
```

Puede ver un ejemplo en [subscription-payu-latam](https://github.com/saulmoralespa/subscription-payu-latam/blob/master/includes/class-subscription-payu-latam.php#L131)